# Dynamic Scrollview Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have made a `Button` which generates `TextFields` and I want a `ScrollView` so if I'd add too much `TextFields` I could scroll and write to them. I also have a `Button` at the bottom of my view and I want this to be visible all the time. (I don't mind if only `TextFields` will be inside the `ScrollView` or the whole view except my bottom button).

[image: This is how it looks like:]

Comment: so what have you done so far? can you show us the code?

Comment: I don't have something for the scrollview. I don't know what is better to put it from storyboard or code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the height constraint on your `TextField`s. Without that, the `scrollView` can't figure out its contentSize. After you set the heights, the `scrollView` will adapt accordingly.

Also, I would use a `UIView` and give a fix height for it and place the `TextField`s inside of the `UIView`.

You can also use `scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: expectedWidth, height: expectedHeight)`

Comment: I generate textfields with this command tf.frame = CGRect(x: 50 ,y:  self.ypos, width: 220, height: 30)  self.scrollView.addSubview(tf) I also use a UiView but again it doesn't scroll

Comment: It's not enough to set the frames, you also have to set constraints. Another solution is to calculate the height of the scrollView and then set the scrollView's contentSize with the following: scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 375, height: yourHeightValue)

Comment: it worked with scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 375, height: yourHeightValue). Update your answer if you want and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

These **steps** help you to design screen according to your requirement :

1. Drag a `ScrollView` and provide height and width accordingly
2. Decrease height of ScrollView by height of Button which you always want to show on bottom of page 
   i.e- Button should be outside of `ScrollView` not within the `ScrollView`
3. Adjust button size and height and put it below to `ScrollView`
4. Now set Constraint to each one . First of all select `ScrollView` provide its l
   **Left** , **Right** , **Top** constraint .
5. Select `ScrollView` and by pressing `Control + drag mouse` to Button ( below of Scrollview) and set vertical spacing between ScrollView and Button
6. Select Button and provide Left , Right , Bottom Constraint.

**Note** - As `AutoLayout` works differently with `ScrollView` so always set constraint of all control within it from Order : `Top To Bottom`

Hope it helps you to fix this issue . Feel free to comment if still any confusion.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! First question can I skip height and width if I use leading trailing and vertical spacing?

Comment: yea height of scrollview is automatically adjusted by its contents so just provide constraint to each of its TextFields , it will work . Also make it correct answer if it solves your problem. Thanks

Comment: More than I can see